# Fail to send kubectl command using aws ssm run command?

Tags: gitlab-ci, kubectl, amazon-eks, aws-ssm

I have an EKS cluster and I am building a CI/CD pipeline using gitlabCI.
In this pipeline I need to connect to my bastion server and after successfully get inside the server I need to send some commands using kubectl to rollout updates for my pods

I already have kubectl installed on my bastion server, but the problem is I am not able to use kubectl command either inside gitlab-ci.yml file or on my local machine using aws ssm run command.

Below is my command.

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids i-0####### --parameters commands="kubectl get pods -n app" --region ap-southeast-3
```

This is what I got from the invocation.

```
"The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?failed to run commands: exit status 1"
```

I tried to send other command to test out the connection between my machine and the bastion server like echo, docker info, and so on. everthing runs smoothly without error.

This is the job for gitlabCI

```
ssm-login:
  stage: ssm-login
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  before_script:
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    - apt-get install wget
    - apt install -y expect
    - wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/session-manager-downloads/plugin/latest/ubuntu_64bit/session-manager-plugin.deb && dpkg -i session-manager-plugin.deb
  script:
    - aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids i-########## --parameters commands="kubectl get pods -n app" --region ap-southeast-3
```

What am I missing here?

your helps will be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you have a kubeconfig?

Comment: yes, I do in my bastion server. I checked the config file in .kube/config and everything looks good. Is there something that I need to check in the config file that could be responsible to this kind of output from AWS?

Comment: The localhost:8080 error makes me think that kubectl is not configured properly. why would it be trying to connect to localhost on that port?

Comment: I forgot to mention that kubectl is working properly if I start a session using ssm to the bastion in interactive mode. It just didn't work if I send the command trough ssm run command

Comment: Guessing it's the user context then. Add a `whoami` to your script to see which user the script is running under.

Comment: It is "root" . Shouldn't it be "ssm-user"? How to change the user context?

Comment: I don't know. You probably need to review the SSM documentation. On Linux, you can use the `su` command to switch users.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks a lot for all your responses. I got the same error when trying to use "kubectl" from another pod. The problem is because I didn't specify the correct serviceaccountname in the configuration YAML, once it is correctly specified it runs smoothly.

Maybe I should find a workaround to tell the server to use the correct serviceaccount for running the job in my runner or the aws ssm run command